# How to add a background picture to a figure in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just want to know the logics of matplotlib.So I tried some strange ideas.I know I can first make axes and then insert a Pic.But now I Want to add a Pic to the whole figure without making axes first. Can I do this?

search on Google and find answer in matplotlib doc.But no answers.They just insert a Pic by first creat axes.